# Gas liquid phase transition : order parameter

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition

I have found that the order parameter for a gas liquid phase transition is the difference of density : $\Delta \rho=\rho_g-\rho_l$.

But I don't understand this definition.

Indeed, an order parameter should be $0$ in one phase and non $0$ in another.

Here, if I only have gas, I will have $\Delta \rho=\rho_g \neq 0$ (indeed, I only have gas so no liquid, so the density of the liquid is $0$) and if I only have liquid I have : $\Delta \rho=\rho_l \neq 0$

Thus I am not sure I understood well...

Comment: This is not a terribly well chosen notation. By $\rho_g$ they just mean $\rho$, the density regardless of what phase it is in. $\Delta\rho$ is then $0$ in the liquid phase and non-zero in the gas phase

Comment: @BySymmetry Oh ok thanks, it is more clear. And I assume that $\rho_l$ is the density of the liquid where the phase transition starts (ok the liquid is almost incompressible but to be accurate this is the good definition)

Comment: Yes, that is correct